# What is meant by renormalising?

Tags: real-analysis

I have a question that asks me to renormalise so that $\left \| \cdot \right \|\leq 1$ as part of an answer I'm not really sure how to do this so any help would be appreciated. Where . is a convergent sequence and the norm takes the max value of the sequence.

Comment: What's the context?

Comment: @lulu . is a sequence and the norm takes the max value of the sequence.

Comment: So, just divide by the max.

Comment: FWIW, I don't think this is really _re_normalization so much as it is just normalization...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think "renormalizing the sequence $(x_n)$", here, means that you have to consider the sequence defined by 
$$y_n = \frac{x_n}{\left\| x_n \right\|}$$
so that you have $\left\| y_n \right\| =1$.